# Schedule cron job for every half hour

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I need to refresh a link every 5 minutes, how to schedule cron for refreshing the url

Answer (score 1):

Tow way to set cron :

**1) cpanel cron set**

```
GoTo Cpanel->corn job setting -> set file path.
```

**2) Using magento . you have to create module .**

app/etc/modules/Compnyname_ModuleName.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Compnyname_ModuleName>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Compnyname_ModuleName>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Compnyname/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Compnyname_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Compnyname_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>Compnyname_ModuleName_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
        <class>Compnyname_ModuleName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
  </global>    
    <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <modulename_cornmethodname>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>modulename/cron::cornmethodname</model></run>
            </modulename_cornmethodname>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**`<cron_expr>set time setting as you want</cron_expr>`**

app/code/local/Compnyname/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Compnyname_ModuleName_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

app/code/local/Compnyname/ModuleName/Model/Cron.php

```
<?php
class Compnyname_ModuleName_Model_Cron{ 
    public function cornmethodname(){
        //do something
    } 
}
```

Set your cron code in Cron.php.

Answer (score 0):

you just point it to your file or page:

```
*/5 * * * *  curl --silent "http://example.come/some/page" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: "-":4: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.  it shows this error

Comment: you can try without `--silent`